# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 (WebRTC)

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, xcode6-beta7

Currently i am building a WebRTC app for iPad (iOS7) using Swift on Xcode 6 beta 7. I keep getting these errors. Have I added wrong libraries? Is it not able to find them?

Here are the errors it's printing:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage", referenced from:
      +[RTCMediaConstraints constraintsFromArray:] in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
      std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint*, std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> > >, webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint const&) in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
  "std::string::assign(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint*, std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> > >, webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint const&) in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
      webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint* std::__copy_backward<false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_b<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint*, webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint*>(webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint*, webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint*, webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint*) in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
      webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint* std::__copy<false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::copy<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint*, webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint*>(webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint*, webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint*, webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint*) in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
      webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint* std::__copy<false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::copy<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint const*, webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint*>(webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint const*, webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint const*, webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint*) in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
  "std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      +[RTCMediaConstraints constraintsFromArray:] in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
      std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint*, std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> > >, webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint const&) in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint>::construct(webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint*, webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint const&) in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
      std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint*, std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> > >, webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint const&) in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
      webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint::Constraint(std::string const&, std::string) in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
      std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> >::operator=(std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> > const&) in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
      webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint* std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> >::_M_allocate_and_copy<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint const*, std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> > > >(unsigned long, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint const*, std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint const*, std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> > >) in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
      std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> >::vector(std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> > const&) in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraintsNative.o)
  "std::__throw_length_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint*, std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> > >, webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint const&) in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint>::construct(webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint*, webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint const&) in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
      std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint*, std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> > >, webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint const&) in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
      webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint::Constraint(std::string const&, std::string) in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
      std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> >::~vector() in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
      std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> >::operator=(std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> > const&) in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
      webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint* std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> >::_M_allocate_and_copy<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint const*, std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> > > >(unsigned long, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint const*, std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint const*, std::vector<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint, std::allocator<webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface::Constraint> > >) in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      +[RTCMediaConstraints constraintsFromArray:] in libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a(RTCMediaConstraints.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help is wonderful.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is older, but... You need to change libstdc++.dylib to libstdc++.6.dylib under "Link Binary with Libraries" in your Build Settings for your App. Annoying, but it worked for me!

Comment: Try to build the framework for this specific architecture. In your case "armv7" That will give you a framework which will resolve these errors. :)